# Node-Resolve error regarding async_hooks on playcode.io

Tags: express, plugins, socket.io, async-hooks, plugin-node-resolve

So I'm trying to create an online chat on "playcode.io". my packages are "express" (ver:4.18.2), "socket.io" (ver:4.7.2), "async_hooks" (ver:1.0.0), & "node-resolve" (ver:1.3.4). I tried to run the project, but it gave me an error message so huge, it goes over the character limit. So instead, I will give my code in snippets, and hopefully that works as a substitute. If you want to see my project as a whole, go to   [my project](https://playcode.io/1659304).

[([image of the files in use.])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZgw1.png)

```html
(Folder;Public 
Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Splat-Chat</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
       <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.glitch.global/c186b68e-b815-42db-b7c3-74070207691c/Logo.webp?v=1673454242039" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="pages">
      <li class="chat page">
        <div class="chatArea">
          <ul class="messages"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs">
          <input class="inputMessage" placeholder="Message...">
          <button class="send">Send</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="login page">
        <div class="form">
          <h3 class="title">Username</h3>

          <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="20" id="usernameInput"/>
          <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
            <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"
              >&times;</a
            >
<hr>
            <!-- Overlay content -->
            <div class="overlay-content">
              <a href="#" onclick="TermsFunction()" style="font-size: 5em">kewl</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu -->
          <button class="loginbutton">Enter</button>
           <div class="tac">
             <br />
             
        </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Splat-Chat", "Hi");
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

does anyone know what this means or why most of it just repeats, and if so, could you please answer why I got this error message and it's solution?